# What is the color and structure of CrO3?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

What is the structure and color of $\ce{CrO3}$?

Also, is it possible to produce $\ce{CrO3}$ when dichromate is heated with sulphuric acid?

Answer (score 4):

According to its [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_trioxide):

**Color**

$\ce{CrO3}$ is a dark-purple solid under anhydrous conditions, that turns bright orange when wet.

**Production**

$\ce{CrO3}$ is generated, as you said, by the following reaction:

$$\ce{H2SO4 + Na2Cr2O7 -> 2 CrO3 + Na2SO4 + H2O}$$

**Structure**

Its monomeric structure is predicted to be pyramidal like so:

[image: chromium oxide monomer]

Its crystalline structure is:

[image: chromium oxide crystal]

Each chromium center shares two oxygen centers with neighbors, but two oxygen atoms are not shared, giving the overall stoichiometric ratio of 1:3.