# Structure of chromium trioxide

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, molecular-structure

According to most sources, $\ce{CrO3}$ has the following Lewis structure (courtesy [ChemSpider](http://chemspider.com/)):

[image]

However, it is also not planar (courtesy Wikipedia):

[image]

Implying that there is a lone pair somewhere.

1. What is the electron configuration of the $\ce{Cr}$ atom?
2. Which orbital is responsible for the three double bonds?
3. Where does the lone pair come from?
4. How would its MO diagram look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the color and structure of CrO3?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31210/what-is-the-color-and-structure-of-cro3)

Comment: @ringo Not even close. None of my questions here is answered there.